# Stunner badge for high upvote/view ratio

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

There should be a badge for getting a high number of upvotes per view. Ten upvotes out of ten views may be too few (it gets Enlightened if accepted, and Nice Answer for sure), but what about 20 out of 20? It'd come before Good Answer and encourage the answering of trivial questions.

Comment: you stole my thunder

Comment: Hey, it was my idea, provoked by your answer, I admit

Comment: thief....! Call the cops

Comment: So what good behavior would this correlate to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think your answer must be somewhat trivial if the first 10 users who see it instantly know it is correct.

Also, if the above happens you're almost guaranteed the Enlightened badge anyways.

Here's some [data](http://statoverflow.com/sandbox/?q=SELECT%20child.Id%20as%20ParentId,%20parent.Id%20as%20PostId,%20child.ViewCount%20as%20Views,%20parent.Score,%20(parent.Score%20/%20child.ViewCount)%20AS%20score%20FROM%20%20posts%20AS%20parent,%20posts%20AS%20child%20WHERE%20parent.ParentId%20=%20child.Id%20AND%20child.ViewCount%20%3E10%20ORDER%20BY%20score%20DESC), I don't know if any user would get this, but dump doesn't account for time votes were placed/time views were made. It does serve as a rough approximation.

Comment: So? It's not like Autobiographer needs one to be a rocket scientist.

Comment: No but it leads to the question of how many badges do we need for trivial actions?

Comment: I wouldn't think you'd get many of these badges (one would have to analyze the dump to be sure). It may reward relatively trivial answers, but those have to be encouraged as well.

Comment: And Nice Answer as well... may be a redundant badge after all

Comment: Excellent link! :)